# PHP (Laravel) loop - every n-th entry

Tags: php, loops, foreach

Haven't found what I was looking for specifically. I only find questions where people break the loop, in my case I do not want to break it. I simply want to insert something special every n-th time.

I have a database with projects, and I want to display them in a grid. I simply loop every row from the database to display it in the grid. But now the client wants to show a customer's quote though out the grid. Mor specifically like this: show 3 projects, place 1 quote, repeat...

[image]

Obviously the 4th item in the loop is very different from the other ones, so I cannot store them in the samen database table. The 'projects' have image and title (among many other things), the quote simply has a name and body.

How would you guys make this as dynamic as possible? Since the client has a CMS where he can add new projects.

Comment: can you publish your code? what loops have you tried?

Comment: Blade has a special [$loop variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#the-loop-variable). Maybe you can check if the iteration divides by 0 evenly and do your logic?

Comment: @Alex You are right my friend. Laravel's blade  `$loop->iteration` is basically the key + 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could declare a counter variable before the foreach statement, and then increment it after each iteration.
You just test if counter % 4 equals 0. If it does, you insert your quote.

Comment: Aah, I kept trying to figure it out with the key (as in `foreach($item as $key => $value)`). But since that starts at 0 it was messing with my order. Declaring a separate variable was the answer.

Comment: Also, laravel's `$loop->iteration` is basically the key + 1. So that might be cleaner code IF you are using Laravel